# How to run Swarm Optimization in a function presented in the same script

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, swarm

I want to run Swarm optimization with a function written in the same script.

```
rng default  % For reproducibility
nvars = 2;
x = particleswarm(fun,nvars)

function val = fun(x)
val=x(1)*exp(x(2));
end
```

When I run this script the promp windows shows me an error.
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just at and @ at the begininf of fun ie:

```
rng default  % For reproducibility
nvars = 2;
x = particleswarm(@fun,nvars)

function val = fun(x)
val=x(1)*exp(x(2));
end
```